# How to set alerts in datadog based on a value of a log =FAIL or =PASS

Tags: logging, events, datadog

I'm trying to set up an alert in datadog if a group of logs show the message FAIL or PASS.

From the docs I can only see alerting that can be done based on a numerical value i.e threshold being off 90% etc.

Does datadog have the functionality where you can send an alert based on a logs text value?

Thanks